# Stored Procedure Execution via Java

Tags: java, sql, azure-synapse

I have a Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool setup. I need to call a stored procedure from the java :
Some stored procedure contains the use of the temporary tables while the other stored procedures do not use temporary tables. The stored procedure without temporary tables are getting executed via my Java application however the stored procedure with temporary tables fails with the following error

```
Distributed transaction completed. Either enlist this session in a new transaction or the NULL transaction.
```

The java code I use to call stored procedure :

```
public DataList(String rowID, int jobID, String userID) {
    Connection conn = null;
    DataEntry gle = null;
    lst = new ArrayList<DataEntry>();
    
    try {
        conn = SqlDBConnectEPM.getConnection("dataDW");
        String sql = "EXEC [dbo].[DATACURSOR_OpenResults] ?,?,?";
        PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        s.setEscapeProcessing(true);
        s.setQueryTimeout(90);
        s.setString(1, rowID);
        s.setInt(2, jobID);
        s.setString(3, userID);
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            gle = new DataEntry(rs);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Configuration.getInstance().getTelemetry().trackEvent("Job Failed for user : " + userID + " for Job : " + jobID);
        Configuration.getInstance().getTelemetry().trackException(e);
    } finally {
        if(conn != null)
        {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                 Configuration.getInstance().getTelemetry().trackException(e);
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot get rid of temporary tables in my stored procedure. Can there be a workaround with the way we call the Stored Procedure from the java code?

The stored procedure executes fine when executed from the SQL server. How do I resolve this issue?